# A question about usage of cloneNode and insertBefore

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to learn some javascript in web programming. Starting with a simple school registration webpage: the webpage allows to dynamically create any number of grades by clicking "Grade+" button; under each grade, any number of students can be created by clicking "Student+" button. "Grade+" button works as expected, however clicking "Student+" button does not present the student information, not sure what is happening. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The reference codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

   <div>
       <label>Registration</label>
       <div class="form-inline justify-content-center" id="school" style="display:none">
           <label for="fname">Grade:</label>
           <input type="text" id="grade" name="Grade"><br><br>
           <div id="students">
               <div id="student">
                   <label for="fname">First:</label>
                   <input type="text" id="first" name="First"><br><br>
                   <label for="lname">Last:</label>
                   <input type="text" id="last" name="Last"><br><br>
               </div>

               <div class="text-center" id="add_student">
                   <span id="idStudentRootCopy">----S----</span>
                   <button type="button" onclick="addItem('student', 'idGradeRootCopy', false)">Student+</button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>

       <div class="text-center" id="add_grade">
           <span id="idGradeRootCopy">----G----</span>
           <button type="button" onclick="addItem('school', 'idGradeRootCopy', true)">Grade+</button>
       </div>
   </div>    
<script>
var count = 0;
function addItem(id, index, root) {
    var original = document.getElementById(id);
    var before = document.getElementById(index);
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.style.display='block';
    clone.id = id + ++count;
    var newFields = clone.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < newFields.length; i++) {
        var fieldName = newFields[i].name;
        if (fieldName)
            newFields[i].name = fieldName + count;
    }    

    if (root) {
        original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, before.parentNode);
    } else {
        original.insertBefore(clone, before);
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the CSS for `#student`?

Comment: You should separate your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. So use external CSS, and JavaScript. You have the `root` argument set to `true` in your Grade button Listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up the developer tools of your browsers and click the **Student+** button you'll get an error message like:

> Uncaught DOMException: Node.insertBefore: Child to insert before is
> not a child of this node

So you're actually trying to put the cloned node into the wrong spot. Either way things are a bit confusing. Let's say you have clicked the **Grade+** button three times and now you decide to click on **Student+** of the first clone - how should it know where to put the student as there are three grades?

Well there's a fix of course. Each **Student+** button is a child of an unique clone of the school `<div>` which you also gave an unique id yet (school1, school2,...). So if you pass the `addItem()` function a reference to the button you actually clicked, we can get it's parent div like:

```
clickedElement.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
```

and add the cloned node using `appendChild()` instead of `insertBefore()`.

Here's an example (just click on 'Run code snippet'):

```js
var count = 0;

function addItem(id, index, root, clickedElement) {
  var original = document.getElementById(id);
  var before = document.getElementById(index);
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);

  clone.style.display = 'block';
  clone.id = id + ++count;
  var newFields = clone.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < newFields.length; i++) {
    var fieldName = newFields[i].name;
    if (fieldName)
      newFields[i].name = fieldName + count;
  }

  if (root) {
    original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, before.parentNode);
  } else {
    clickedElement.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Registration</label>
  <div class="form-inline justify-content-center" id="school" style="display:none">
    <label for="fname">Grade:</label>
    <input type="text" id="grade" name="Grade"><br><br>
    <div id="students">
      <div id="student">
        <label for="fname">First:</label>
        <input type="text" id="first" name="First"><br><br>
        <label for="lname">Last:</label>
        <input type="text" id="last" name="Last"><br><br>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center" id="add_student">
        <span id="idStudentRootCopy">----S----</span>
        <button type="button" onclick="addItem('student', 'idGradeRootCopy', false,this)">Student+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center" id="add_grade">
    <span id="idGradeRootCopy">----G----</span>
    <button type="button" onclick="addItem('school', 'idGradeRootCopy', true,this)">Grade+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Update

If you click on the **Grade+** button, it will automatically also 'create' a student input field as it's div is part of the school div. So move it out of the school div and change it's display mode to none.

If you want the new student input field to appear right before the **Student+** button, we indeed need to use `.insertBefore()`.

Here's the modified example:

```js
var count = 0;

function addItem(id, index, root, clickedElement) {
  var original = document.getElementById(id);
  var before = document.getElementById(index);
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);

  clone.style.display = 'block';
  clone.id = id + ++count;
  var newFields = clone.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < newFields.length; i++) {
    var fieldName = newFields[i].name;
    if (fieldName)
      newFields[i].name = fieldName + count;
  }

  if (root) {
    original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, before.parentNode);
  } else {
    clickedElement.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, clickedElement);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Registration</label>
  <div id="student" style="display:none">
    <label for="fname">First:</label>
    <input type="text" id="first" name="First"><br><br>
    <label for="lname">Last:</label>
    <input type="text" id="last" name="Last"><br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="form-inline justify-content-center" id="school" style="display:none">
    <label for="fname">Grade:</label>
    <input type="text" id="grade" name="Grade"><br><br>
    <div id="students">
      <div class="text-center" id="add_student">
        <span id="idStudentRootCopy">----S----</span>
        <button type="button" onclick="addItem('student', 'idStudentRootCopy', false,this)">Student+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center" id="add_grade">
    <span id="idGradeRootCopy">----G----</span>
    <button type="button" onclick="addItem('school', 'idGradeRootCopy', true,this)">Grade+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am kind of very unfamiliar with DOM. My original attempt was just based on the following thought: 1) leave a "Grade" section w/o any "Student" when it is created. 2) when clicking "Student+" button, a new student info will be created and put right in front of the "Student+" button which is clicked. Not sure if it is doable or how to do it(if doable). But the development tools might be very helpful

Comment: A typo in my original codes, 'idGradeRootCopy' should be 'idStudentRootCopy': 
              <div class="text-center" id="add_student">
                   <span id="idStudentRootCopy">----S----</span>
                   <button type="button" onclick="addItem('student', 'idGradeRootCopy', false)">Student+</button>
               </div>
But it still doesn't work. Probable I need learn more :)

Comment: Now I know what you mean. I've updated my answer!

Comment: Thanks, that's perfectly what I want to achieve

Comment: Glad I could help NotFun! By the way - if you think this is the correct answer please consider accepting it using the 'tick' button.